# Error on create instance of custom member resolver in AutoMapper 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper 6 (AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) for mapping data and view models in a .net core web api application.I have an age property on view model and use custom resolver for calculate age according to birth date come from data model.

This is how i add AutoMapper in StartupClass:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config => config.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfiles()));
```

And this is AutoMapper profile class:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDetailDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
            })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom<AgeResolverForUserDetail>();
        });

        CreateMap<User, UserListDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt =>
            {
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
            })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom<AgeResolverForUserList>();
        });

        CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDTO>();
    }
}
```

And this is AgeResolverForUserDetail:

```
public class AgeResolverForUserDetail : IValueResolver<User, UserDetailDTO, int>
{
    public int Resolve(User source, UserDetailDTO destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.BirthDate.CalculateAge();
    }
}
```

When i run my app and try to get a user detail, mapping objects throw an exception:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type DatingApp.Utility.AutoMapperUtilities.AgeResolverForUserDetail
AutoMapper.MappingOperationOptions.CreateInstance() in MappingOperationOptions.cs, line 47
AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
User -> UserDetailDTO
DatingApp.Models.DataModels.User -> DatingApp.Models.ViewModels.UserDetailDTO
Type Map configuration:
User -> UserDetailDTO
DatingApp.Models.DataModels.User -> DatingApp.Models.ViewModels.UserDetailDTO
Destination Member:
Age**

Can you give me a solution for this?

thanks

Comment: I can't seem to find such `MapFrom` overload in AM6, are you sure you are not using some newer AM version (like 8)?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I use this package: AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection and installed version is 6

Comment: Ok, if you use [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/), then you can see that it has dependency on AutoMapper (>= 8.0.0). Please correct that, because different AM versions have different features (and problems :)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thanks for your answer, i add automapper 8 and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.1 to both main project and utility project, but unfortunately see that error again

Comment: I just meant to update the information in the question. I can't reproduce, and not sure what @LucianBargaoanu (one of the AM contributors) means by the link he posted. Hopefully he could explain more. Meanwhile I would suggest trying `opt.MapFrom(new AgeResolverForUserDetail());`

Comment: That link explains how the DI extension works. You have to pass assemblies that are scanned for AM types. So that resolver is not found because its assembly was not scanned.

Comment: @Lucian But they are adding it explicitly in the configuration action via `opt.MapFrom<AgeResolverForUserDetail>();`, so there shouldn't be a need to "find" it, no?

Comment: When using the DI extension all AM types are resolved through DI.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Stoev..Thank you Lucian Bargaoanu... I use opt.MapFrom(new AgeResolverForUserDetail()); and it works fine. I don't know why my last code didn't work because as explained here [link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/TestApp/Program.cs) it should works.