# AutoMapper producing error when mapping from 2 sources to destination using customResolver

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two sources like

```
public class Source1 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Source2ID { get; set; }
    ... //Other Fields

}
```

Source2 like

```
public class Source2 : Entity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

And a destination class as follows

```
public class destination
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Source2ID { get; set; }
    public string Source2Name {get;set;}
    ... //Other Fields

}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is map the source2 name in the destination with the source2ID available in the source1.

What i have tried is to use a custom value resolver.

```
 public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Source1, Destination, string>
{

    private readonly IRepository<Source2> _suiteRepository;

    public CustomResolver(IRepository<Source2> suiteRepository )
    {
        _suiteRepository = suiteRepository;
    }

    public string Resolve(Source1 source, Destination destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _suiteRepository.Get(source.Source2ID).Name;
    }
}
```

And then in the config, I'm creating the map as follows.

```
config.CreateMap<Source1, Destination>()
  .ForMember(u => u.Name, options => options.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

Following is the code that's calling the mapper

```
var source1 = await _repository
     .GetAll()
     .ToListAsync();

var destinationList = ObjectMapper.Map<List<Destination>>(source1);
```

This however produces the following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions, ref bool canBeCached, ref RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor)

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Destination
Source1

Type Map configuration:
Source1-> Destinatinon
Namespace.Source1 -> Namespace.Destination

Property:
Source2Name
lambda_method(Closure , List<Sourc1> , List<Destination> , ResolutionContext )

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
```

I am new to AutoMapper, I have searched google but couldn't find something on this. I'm not sure if there is a better way to map these together.

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656777/error-on-create-instance-of-custom-member-resolver-in-automapper-6

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Redirected by Lucian, CustomResolver needs to be initialized first. i.e From the Automapper documentation

> Once we have our IValueResolver implementation, we’ll need to tell AutoMapper to use this custom value resolver when resolving a specific destination member. We have several options in telling AutoMapper a custom value resolver to use, including:
>
> MapFrom< TValueResolver>
>
> MapFrom(typeof(CustomValueResolver))
>
> MapFrom(aValueResolverInstance)

Using the third option, solved the problem.
i.e

```
config.CreateMap<Source1, Destination>()
  .ForMember(u => u.Name, options => options.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver());
```

However in my case, since I had the repository as the parameter for the Resolver, I had to resolve the scoped Repository from the service provider .

Since, i'm using AbpBoilerplate, my code look like this.

```
 using (var repo = Configuration.Modules.AbpConfiguration.IocManager.CreateScope().ResolveAsDisposable<IRepository<Source2>>())
 {

     config.CreateMap<Source1, Destination>()
          .ForMember(u => u.Name, options => options.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver(repo.Object)));
 }
```

Comment: AM supports integration with [DI](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) but I have no idea how would that work with AbpBoilerplate.

Comment: I saw that, AbpBoilerplate supports DI as well, but since the configuration goes in a Application Module (like a startup file), I had to resolve it from the provider.